# Append multiple columns to single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

When I plot this, I get the following:

[image: Plot]

But what I want is that the values of all the columns should be appended to one single columns so that I can obtain just one single line.
I mean, there should be no column number 4,5,6,7. Just one single column with the values of all these.
My Problem:

1. Not able to convert Index from month names to 0,1,2,3,. I have used Set_Index but it didnt work
2. Used Append command with drop index but didn't get any results.

I m just one day old in learning pandas. Kindly give me lead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
single_column_frame = pd.concat([df[col] for col in df.columns])
```

If you want to create a single column and get rid of month names:

```
df_new = df.melt()['value'].to_frame()
```

Or you can do:

```
single_column_frame = single_column_frame.reset_index().drop(columns=['index'])
```

You can also do:

```
single_column_frame = df.stack().reset_index().loc[:,0]
```